# mongodb grant all with wildcard role like mysql

Tags: mongodb

is it possible to grant a user in mongodb to access multiple databases using some sort of regex?
for example in MySql i can use

```
grant all on `example\_%`.* to `example`@`localhost`;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do that in MongoDB as the db value when setting user roles has to be a string, [source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createRole/#db.createRole). However, you can write a script to help you achieve the same result. I came up with this(the script itself is small, however, comments and logging make it seem long):

```
// script.js

// Change the value of this variable to the name of the database expected to store the user details
const userDatabase = 'test';

// Change the value of this variable to the name of the user to grant the roles
const userName = 'user';

// Get a list of all database matching the regExp /^example.*$/
const dbs = db.adminCommand({ listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true, filter: { name: /^example.*$/ } });
print('Found ' + dbs.databases.length + ' matching databases');

// Compose the user roles
// You can remove or add more roles here
const roles = dbs.databases.map(({ name }) => ({ role: 'readWrite', db: name }));

// Change to the database expected to store the user details
const userDb = db.getSiblingDB(userDatabase);

if (userDb.getUser(userName)) {
  // If the user already exists, update the user roles
  print('User already exist, granting roles...');
  userDb.grantRolesToUser(userName, roles);
} else {
  // If the user does not exist, create the user and add roles
  print('User does not exist, creating a user...');
  userDb.createUser({
    user: userName,
    pwd: passwordPrompt(), // This would prompt a password for the new user. The password can also be written in clear text here
    roles,
  });
}
```

You would run the script like this:

```
// Replace <host> and <port> with the host and port values of your mongoDB server. 
// Replace <adminUserName> with the userName of the admin user
mongo <host>:<port>/admin script.js -u <adminUserName> --authenticationDatabase "admin" -p
```

A password prompt would appear after running the command above, you should enter the password of the admin user.